# left join table with no duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables -

t1:

```
col_1        col_2        col_3
10001        apple        3
10001        orange       2
10001        grapes       5
```

t2:

```
col_1        col_2        col_3        col_4
10001        apple        3            123
10001        orange       2            345
```

What SQL query would join these two tables; giving me a result like this:

```
col_1        col_2        col_3        col_4
10001        apple        3            123
10001        orange       2            345
10001        grapes       5
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your desired results appear to be an identical copy of your first table. Your second table appears to be a simple subset of your first table. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: how about if the column for each table is not same? i already edited my question, thanks

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks for updating the question. Could there ever be a record in the second table that _isn't_ in the first table? Or will all records always be in the first table, with only some of those also being in the second table?

Comment: Please correct tags. They should be mysql OR sql-server, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Join tables, then use COALESCE to get the first non null data column

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.col_1,t2.col_1) col_1,
   COALESCE(t1.col_2,t2.col_2) col_2,
   COALESCE(t1.col_3,t2.col_3) col_3,
   COALESCE(t2.col_4,'') col_4,
FROM t1
FULL JOIN t2 ON t1 ON t1.col_1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col_2 = t2.col_2 AND t1.col_3 = t2.col_3
```

Comment: how about if the column for each table is not same? i already edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3 
FROM t1)

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3 
FROM t2)
```

Comment: Plain UNION is ok to return distinct rows, UNION DISTINCT is incorrect syntax for SQL server

Comment: how about if the column for each table is not same? i already edited my question, thanks

Comment: The first SELECT will set the alias for all columns. 
That means that you can have col_4, col_5 and for instance col_6 in the second table, but you will still access these 3 columns as col_1, col_2 and col_3. 
Just remember to have the same amount of columns in each UNION SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.col_1, t1.col_2, t1.col3, t2.col_4
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.col_1 = t2.col_1 AND t1.col_2 = t2.col_2 AND t1.col_3 = t2.col_3
```

Comment: By joining only col_1 your query will return 3x2 = 6 rows instead of 3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       col_4 
FROM   t1 
       LEFT JOIN t2 using(col_2);
```

If col_1 and col_2  identify a unique entry change the last line to:

```
LEFT JOIN t2 using(col_1,col_2);
```

If col_1, col_2, col_3 identify a unique entry change the last line to:

```
LEFT JOIN t2 using(col_1,col_2,col_3);
```